# where should I get a full list of colors, linetypes, etc. supported in gnuplot?

Tags: colors, gnuplot

Where should I get a full list of colors, linetypes, etc. supported in gnuplot?
I could not find extensive list in the mannual.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: See the gnuplot standard colors visualized here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599

Answer (score 10):

You can see this using gnuplot commands. For example:

Color names: `show colornames`

Line types: `show linetypes`

Show available line/point styles, pattern styles etc for the current terminal on the graph: the command `test`.

Answer (score 3):

I searched for the same and couldn't find relevant documentation until i downloaded the application.
Below are the few steps that helped me locate the list of colors etc:

1. Download the Gnuplot application and open gnuplot

Refer to the image
[image: on search bar type]

This open the Gnuplot window
[image: This open the Gnuplot window]

2. Now type ***show colornames***. This will show the list of colors supported in the current gnuplot. Refer to the below image.

[image: List of colors]

3. For more information, type ***help show*** and it display the documentation.

Comment: See them visualized here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54659829/7295599